# Incorrect date on FTP server?

Tags: ftp

I have a very general question. I just connected to a client's FTP server to download a file.
 Because there are a huge number of files, I thought I'd search by the "Date Modified", which didn't work in this case.

See the screenshot below, which shows that all files have a date modified year of 2004 (including the one I was looking for).

Would this be a result of the FTP server having an incorrect date? Should I inform my client of this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The time & date are probably wrong on the server.